# Разный формат вывода даты datetime. Python

Tags: python, datetime

При вызове `date.today()` получается дата в формате: `2022-04-14`.
При вызове `date.today().month` мы получаем номер месяца в формате: `4`.
Как получить число или месяц в формате `04`, для сравнения с числами в бд через `strftime('%m')`

```py
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

print(today)  # 2022-04-09
print(today.year, today.month, today.day)  # 2022 4 9, а нужно 04 и 09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это связано с тем, что выводится в первом случае строка в формате ISO через метод:

```
def isoformat(self):
    ...
    return "%04d-%02d-%02d" % (self._year, self._month, self._day)
```

А для второго случая целые числа. В этом случае Вы можете сами отформатировать вывод:

```
month = f"{today.month:02d}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что `today` возвращает строку, которая может начинаться с нуля, а `month` возвращает число, ноль перед которым не имеет смысла. Можно исспользовать форматирование строк.

```
today = date.today()

print(today)  # 2022-04-09
print(today.year, '{0:0>2}'.format(today.month), today.day)
'''
2022-04-14
2022 04 14
'''
```